# Quote only answer to a low-quality question

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

So here's the question:

[image]

Initial thought was... LMGTFY... then an answer arrived.

The answer shows as little effort as the question, as it's a simple copy and paste of a paragraph from an external site, which to a degree adds some content to Stack Overflow, but nothing that can't be googled in seconds.

[image]

I used my voting powers as well as editing the answer to properly attribute it's origin, but is there other actions that should be taken on either question or answer in cases like this?

What would be a suitable close reason? Off Topic > Other?

Comment: The edit has saved that answer -- the content was originally posted without quote formatting or attribution of any kind, which was nothing more than plagiarism. That problem is "fixed" now, and the answer does have value, so it arguably should remain.

Comment: The user that answered only recently obtained the close vote privilege, might need to learn to use that privilege?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I saw it and it looked like a quote so I formatted it as such after checking, then posted this to verify any other actions. I probably would have provided a link like that in comments if I had nothing further to add.

Comment: delete this question

Comment: I don't think answers like that need to be "fixed" or "saved". Just flag them as plagiarized and request deletion. If you're going to ape someone else's content, you need to at least provide something original, too.

Comment: @Cody, I see your point, but the questioner fixing the post with proper style and attribution looks to me like the best thing to do in the short term -- *and*, I agree, also invalidates this very question a little because the problem has already been dealt with :) That said, both solutions are fine IMHO, and the questioner's choice may very well end up being the best one after all.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I like to believe that proper formatting and attribution, among other things, should be the sole responsibility of the user posting the answer and that editors should not be "helping" them. That's like putting in all the citations for your students when they submit their stolen work so they don't have to (albeit as a sly way of telling them "I know you didn't write this").

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: This is why, instead of editing their answers for them, we delete them outright and ask the user to edit their answers themselves.

Comment: @BoltClock in fairness to the user he did link the resource in the post, he just didn't make it clear it was a quote, perhaps he was unaware of how to do this and I should have commented and requested he performed that edit instead of doing it myself.

Comment: @xzy I'm not going to delete this, even though you asked so politely, but I have removed the direct link to the actual question. The whole point of meta is to discuss issues around Stack Overflow, which is what I am doing. If you have questions or queries about posts and behaviour, this is the place to get feedback.

Comment: There is only 1 suitable close reason for that question, and that is **duplicate**

Comment: Didn't @xzy mean to delete the SO question, rather than this MSO question? (I see that the SO question has now been deleted in any case.)

Comment: @chiastic-security I'm not sure, he never made it clear or came back to comment.

Comment: No, he meant to delete the Meta question. It was attracting attention to his Stack Overflow question, which he found unwelcome because the attention was largely negative. Which is completely reasonable; he'd asked a low-quality question, not likely to be thought highly of by the community. Like @chiastic-security said, he's deleted it now, which solves the problem for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't attempt to judge the amount of effort put into a question or an answer.  It's the results of the effort that are important.  The effort itself is only a means of getting there.

As for the question.  You should determine whether It's understandable, on-topic, unique and answerable.  If it's all of those, then It's a fine question regardless of perceived "effort"

---

You should do similar with the answer.

Evaluate whether it's correct, and helpful to people with that question.

Try to consider whether or not you'd have a problem with it if that exact quote and citation was just a part a larger more wordy answer.

If it passes both of those tests, then it's a fine answer, and you can leave it alone.

---

In the case of this question, since the answerer posted a link to where the quote came from, he didn't appear to be maliciously plagiarizing so much as failing to properly format his quote.

Editing is the correct course of action in that case.

Comment: In general, isn't one of the criteria for a down vote, "shows little research effort", in which case we are (on some posts) judging effort, which I think is valid.

Comment: @Tanner, that's only for a question, because of people asking without doing a lot of research first.  It's ok to answer without having to do a lot of research if you have the correct answer.

Comment: @LanceRoberts that's correct, I was simply responding to: _You shouldn't attempt to judge the amount of effort put into a question..._